# MvvM ViewModel to ViewModel Communication

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I have two view models `ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` they both use a common `DataServiceA` to retrieve a User Setting called `Theme`.  `ViewModel`B can change that setting and save it to the database. When this occurs the `ViewModelA` does not update that theme value.
I have been trying to figure out the proper course of action to allow it to update it as well and have come up with a few options:

1. Make the DataService raise a property notification when a value is saved (I don't like this)
2. Use MessengerService to keep them in sync. (I am having issues running into a messaging loop)
3. Pass one ViewModel to the other

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you conisded using events? If ViewModelB saves the data to a theme, it can raise an event. ViewModelA can subscribe to the event and call data service to refresh its version of theme. And vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of them use the same instance of `DataServiceA`, I don't think it's such a bad idea that `DataServiceA` will also implement **[INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)** and raise an event when the `Theme` property changes.

But if you don't like that idea, another option is to use the **[EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)** and publish the event. I personally think the first option is quite sufficient but it's your call...

Comment: I am new to MVVM and MVVM light and for some reason I felt that binding to a property in the dataservice violated the intention of it

Comment: Binding from the ViewModel to the Model is ok... Some people even put the Model as a `Public Property` on the ViewModel so the View can see it. Others expose all of the Model fields as Properties on the ViewModel so the View will not have access to the Model itself - both of these methods don't break the MVVM pattern

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good case for using events, if they both have access to DataServiceA could you not raise an event when the theme is changed?

So.. in the DataServiceA, "OnThemeChanged" event is raised when the theme is modified and the ViewModels can subscribe to the event and update their content when it is raised.